# How to simplify this C code?

Tags: c, dictionary, hashtable

I want to simplify the following code in C. Is there any hash table in C to make it simple? For example "dict" in Python.

```
int a, b, c, d ......

a = get_value_from_sth( A_NAME )

b = get_value_from_sth( B_NAME )

c = get_value_from_sth( C_NAME )

d = get_value_from_sth( D_NAME )

......
```

Comment: Why not using an array with constants as indexes?

Comment: C does not come with any standard dictionary or hashtable data structures.

Comment: @pierre I think he is looking to be able to use any data type (like a string) for a key...not just integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [glib hash tables](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.28/glib-Hash-Tables.html).  Not "official" or "built in," but widely used and as close as you can get to a standard hash table implementation for C.

Answer (score 1):

No, C does not have a built-in hash table type like Python's dicts. You may be able to get by with an array, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a function to map a ptr to a value in an array.

This is how python does it.
http://docs.python.org/c-api/dict.html

Personally I do not bother. It's C.  The best solution will still be ugly.